# ScrollTo function doesn't scroll to bottom in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a list of messages that are stored in an array and then displayed to the screen via a loop, which is within a `ScrollView`. What i want is when the view is loaded the scroll view is scrolled all the way to the bottom, which i attempted to do with the `scrollTo` function, however the scroll view stayed in the same position no matter what value i passed into it. Can someone help point me in the right direction on how to do this.

```
struct MessageList2: View {
    @Binding var messages: [String]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { value in
            ScrollView() {
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    ForEach(0..<messages.count, id: \.self) { index in
                        Text(messages[index])
                    }
                    
                }
                .onAppear{
                    value.scrollTo(messages.count)
                }
                
            }
        }
        
    
    
    }
    
    }
```

Note the 'messages array receives value from another function and works just fine

I tried following examples online that showed how to use the `ScrollView` and `scrollTo()` and tried to implement it myself however the view stayed the same. Im assuming that im using the function wrong.
I also tried adding a `.id(index)` under `Text()` but that didnt seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an off-by-one error. Note the id's you are assigning to each items are the same the index of the elements. The max index that can appear in `messages` is `messages.count - 1`, which means the max possible id is `messages.count - 1`.

So instead of `scrollTo(messages.count)`, you probably meant to `scrollTo(messages.count - 1)`.